# How to get the default CALENDAR_ID in Android?

Tags: android, calendar, android-calendar, calendarcontract

I am trying to add Events in my app using a calender.According to [CalenderContract](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.html),I need to provide a constant ID each time I add an event to the calender.I don't know how to do that.

I tried using `calender_ID =1` which worked on some devices and `calender_ID = 3` which also worked on some devices.

I think there would be some default ID which can be used to make this work properly.

Can anyone please tell me how this can be done?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get the calender id by this following code :

```
    String projection[] = {"_id", "calendar_displayName"};
    Uri calendars;
    calendars = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/calendars");

    ContentResolver contentResolver = c.getContentResolver();
    Cursor managedCursor = contentResolver.query(calendars, projection, null, null, null);

    if (managedCursor.moveToFirst()){
        m_calendars = new MyCalendar[managedCursor.getCount()];
        String calName;
        String calID;
        int cont= 0;
        int nameCol = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(projection[1]);
        int idCol = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(projection[0]);
        do {
            calName = managedCursor.getString(nameCol);
            calID = managedCursor.getString(idCol);
            m_calendars[cont] = new MyCalendar(calName, calID);
            cont++;
        } while(managedCursor.moveToNext());
        managedCursor.close();
    }
```

So you can get the calender Id at runtime and use it . you don't need hardcoded 1 or 3 column Id.

Comment: can you tell me what MyCalendar []  is? @chandrakant

Comment: my method will take return type of calendar thatswhy i took that but you dont need that i edit my code for you

Comment: which calendar_id should use to insert event

Comment: Does this returns the default calendar or simply the first one added to the device?